# Monitoring CANBus into PC - RS232 - Touch Encoder

Tags: serial-port, monitoring, can-bus

I purchased this device for a hobby project
http://www.grayhill.com/touch-encoder/

It outputs as CANBus (via DB9 connector). I'm not very savvy with these types of serials, but I just want to be able to just sniff/monitor the data packets from this device into my PC.

I bought myself a PCI Serial COM (RS232), and hooked it all up, and downloaded multiple monitoring software, however no data appears to be coming from the Bus.

Again, I'm not too savvy with this, so I don't know if I have configuration correct? Such as Baud rate, Data bits, Parity, etc.

The software I'm using is 'Device Monitoring Studio 8.30' (trial version). The software can see my PCI Card with the Ports; Monitoring does not return anything.

Am I missing something here? My understanding is that CANBus works with RS232.
Thanks

Comment: "It outputs as CANBus" ... "I bought myself a PCI Serial COM (RS232)". Err... DB9 connector doesn't automatically mean RS232. You bought the wrong device. CAN and RS232 are different physical standards. Should have spent your money on a book about CAN instead. What you need is a CAN-to-USB adapter. The most well-known vendors are Vector, IXXAT and Kvaser, though there are plenty of cheaper (and lower quality) alternatives. You often get a simple CAN listener software as part of the deal when you buy one. Good listeners for professional use cost more.

Comment: That being said, this isn't a programming question. Asking about CAN protocols, CAN APIs, stacks or drivers is on-topic, asking about how to install CAN tools is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CAN bus and RS232 don't understand each other at the physical level, they use different voltages. And they are not compatible at the higher network layers either.

You need to get yourself a CAN to RS232 converter.

There are some options but all I know of are expensive +100$ US.

I would rather go for one of [these](https://canable.io/) which you can plug directly on a USB port on your computer.

Note that I'm not affiliated with the developers and I have not tested this product myself. You should do your own research to make sure you're buying the product that fits your needs best.

You seem to be on Windows so you might want to check [cangaroo](https://github.com/HubertD/cangaroo/blob/master/README.md).